# Huawei Router Telnet and SSH configuration - Authentication

Tags: router, huawei

I am following Huawei user guide to enable telnet server and telnet service to a port. However, whenever I am trying to do a telnet, I see this error and the connection times out -

```
HUAWEI %%01SOCKET/4/TCP_AUTH_FAILED(s)[45]:TCP authentication failed.  (AuthenticationType=KeyChain, Cause=no local digest, SourceAddress=21.13.30.147, SourcePort=22, ForeignAddress=10.42.87.97, ForeignPort=45387, Protocol=Unknow Protocol, VpnInstanceName=)
```

I don't what am I missing here. How to troubleshoot this?

This router is connected with a normal switch and I am trying to access this through my PC. I can access the interface IP - 21.13.30.147 but I can't telnet or ssh.

Here is my display this for aaa

```
[HUAWEI-aaa]display this
#
aaa
 local-user root password cipher $1a$$z[[J^af*7$D/giK-@j'9.qB"9$$p>!<k>*Yd.IE,{Dnv(.tbDG$
 local-user root service-type terminal telnet ssh
 local-user root level 15
 local-user root state active
 local-user root access-limit 48
 authentication-scheme default0
 authentication-scheme default1
 authentication-scheme default
  authentication-mode local radius
 authentication-scheme l-h
  authentication-mode local
 authentication-scheme telnetcheck
  authentication-mode local
 #
 authorization-scheme default
 #
 accounting-scheme default0
 accounting-scheme default1
 accounting-scheme default
 #
 domain default_admin
  accounting-scheme default0
 domain default_8021x                     
  accounting-scheme default0
 #
#
return
[HUAWEI-aaa]
```

Here are the details

```
<HUAWEI>display version 
Huawei Versatile Routing Platform Software
VRP (R) software, Version 5.160 (ATN 910I DC V200R005C00SPC100)
Copyright (C) 2013-2014 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
HUAWEI ATN 910I DC uptime is 0 day, 13 hours, 17 minutes
ATN 910I DC version information:

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
CXP version information:

CXP(Master) 2  : uptime is 0 day, 13 hours, 17 minutes
         StartupTime   2017/05/24   23:37:47 
  SDRAM Memory Size   : 512M bytes
  FLASH Memory Size   : 128M bytes
  CFCARD Memory Size : 122M bytes 
  CXP version information
  PCB         Version : 910I DC REV B
  FPGA1       Version : V220
  CPLD1       Version : V200
  PE          Version : 000
  BootROM     Version : 8.60.69
  BootLoad    Version : 9.60.69
  Software    Version : Version 5.160 RELEASE 0001
<HUAWEI>
```

Here are other configs

```
[HUAWEI]display this
#
sysname HUAWEI
#
vlan batch 100
#
undo telnet ipv6 server enable
#
radius enable
#
energy conservation disable
#
over-temperature protection enable
#
lldp enable
#
ip route-static 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 NULL0
ip route-static 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/2/5
ip route-static 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 LoopBack0
ip route-static 10.12.0.0 255.255.0.0 11.213.60.1
ip route-static 10.16.0.0 255.255.0.0 11.213.60.1
ip route-static 11.213.0.0 255.255.0.0 11.213.60.1
#
undo ssh server compatible-ssh1x enable
stelnet server enable
ssh user root                             
ssh user root authentication-type password
ssh user root service-type stelnet
#
lldp enable-dcn authentication %#%#H=9zRo)P=5!)wNK={pB4MHFo"(c#3VxQ7GL"k<bD%#%#
#
return
```

What is the authentication problem here. I am using aaa authentication on vty 0 -14.

Comment: This is ATN 910. I am doing telnet from pc to the management IP. I am not sure why I am getting those telnet authentication failure.